# Why is it the convention of some programmers to use long bit shifts instead of directly assigning a value / storing it as a constant

Tags: c, assembly, bit-shift

Consider the following code from the [wikipedia article on square root algorythms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Binary_numeral_system_.28base_2.29)

```
short isqrt(short num) {
     short res = 0;
     short bit = 1 << 14; // The second-to-top bit is set: 1 << 30 for 32 bits

     // "bit" starts at the highest power of four <= the argument.
     while (bit > num)
        bit >>= 2;

     while (bit != 0) {
        if (num >= res + bit) {
            num -= res + bit;
            res = (res >> 1) + bit;
        }
        else
            res >>= 1;
        bit >>= 2;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Why would someone ever do this:

```
short bit = 1<< 14;
```

Instead of just assigning the value directly:

```
short bit = 0x4000;
```

Some RISC instruction sets will let you shift by a given amount, which is handy. MIPS lets you supply the `shamt` parameter for example. Other instruction sets aren't so handy. An MSP430 (16 bit - not the extended instructions) compiler would need to render this as a looped call to the `RLA` pseudo instruction I suppose.

So in some cases it seems like it does not 'hurt' to do it this way, but in other cases it seems like it could. So is there ever an advantage to having long shifts like that? Because it seems like it would make code less portable in a certain sense.

Do X86 or other CISC machines do something magical with this that I just don't know about? :)

Comment: Most compilers do constant folding, so the expression `1 << 14` is pretty much always going to be evaluated at compile time anyway.  It's a bit more readable way to say "set the 14th bit" than encoding it as hexadecimal.

Comment: Actually I guess that would be the 15th bit. So there goes a small part of my readability argument.... ;)

Comment: @cdhowie Its 14th or 15th bit depending on if one counts from 1 or 0.  Its also a holy war.

Comment: I count from 0 and so does my 64bit calculator app, so it's all good for me anyway.

Comment: NOTE using signed integers for bitops is dangerous. Using signed ints for isqrt() is madness. Note2: Newton/Ralphston converges in 4 iterations for 32 bit (unsigned) ints, so you can avoid loops.

Comment: I have no hardware division / floating point support, but the particulars of square root algorithms are the subject of many other threads. I agree about signed values though - this is just what I saw on wikipedia.

Comment: I don't blame you. Since the wikipediacode is intended to demonstrate the *algorithm* it is acceptable. It is not perfect, nor optimal. For demonstration-purposes it is clearer to stick to one convention. (either shift, or multiply/divide, but don't mix them; that would confuse people) But your question comments on the *efficiency* of the code, which is probably pretty bad, because it was intended as a demonstration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is just more explicit, and, as it involves only constants, will most certainly be evaluated at compile time, not at run time, so in the end, the resulting code will be exactly the same.

Comment: My +1 gave got you to 3000 rep. You're welcome. :)  (JK, it was all you.)

Comment: @Jashaszun 3000 isn't an impressive number. `1 << 12`, aka 4096 on the other hand... ;)

Comment: AH HA! So the answer is the processor isn't really left shifting at all! Thanks for the fast response. You saved my head from several minutes of extra scratching.

Comment: @Nick The processor is doing left shifting. The question is when: it's doing it once, when the program is being compiled, rather than every time the program is being run.

Comment: Well - in my case it is my PC's GHz Clocked X86 processor doing it and not my tiny low power MHz clocked uC. So I should have more correctly said "My target processor is never really left shifting"

Answer (score 3):

C has **integer constant expressions**, which lend themselves to evaluation during translation.  That is why you can do things like this:

```
enum {
    foo_bit,
    bar_bit,
    baz_bit,
    foo_flag = 1 << foo_bit,
    bar_flag = 1 << bar_bit,
    baz_flag = 1 << baz_bit
  };
static unsigned int some_flags = bar_flag | baz_flag;
```

Because it has **static** duration, the initializer for **some_flags** must be an integer constant expression; computable during translation.  What we give it certainly is, even though there are multiple computations involved.  This example only has one magic number: 1.

Comment: Excellent example and explanation, Shao!

Comment: Yes, thanks, putting it in the enum makes it very clear that it is evaluated prior to run time.

Comment: A switch-case would make it even more obvious that they do in-fact get evaluated to constants. ... `case (bar_flag | baz_flag) :`...

Comment: technosaurus: I don't know why that would be any more obvious. :)  **case** and **enum** have the same constraint, regarding ICE.  Perhaps you believe that most people are more aware of the **case** constraint than the **enum** constraint.  Perhaps that's so; I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

More options to match documentation.  Whatever is driving the code, drives the style.

A supporting document may say the 14th bit (of a range 0 to 15) is set and the following code relates directly to that.  Note `1 << 14` is `signed`.

```
int x = 1 << 14;
```

Docs may say use mask `0x4000`, then the following is better. Note `0x4000` is `unsigned`.

```
int mask = 0x4000;
```

---

Answer (score 1):

It's more readable and just as @jcaron said, it will all be the same thing
after all. Here is the relevant part if I compile to assembly, not even
optimised, just `-S`:

```
_isqrt:                                 ## @isqrt

[...]

Ltmp4:
        .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
        movw    %di, %ax
        movw    %ax, -2(%rbp)
        movw    $0, -4(%rbp)
        movw    $16384, -6(%rbp)        ## imm = 0x4000
```

Writing `16384`, `0x4000` or `1<<14` in this declaration is a matter of
preference.

Maybe even if your compiler supports it, why not `0b10000000000000`? :-)

Comment: `16384, 0x4000, 1<<14` are `signed`, `unsigned` and `signed`.  In certain contexts, it may make an important difference, thought not here.

Comment: @chux Yes certainly. But what I mean is that writing any of these in this case, in front of a signed short declaration, will result in the same thing.

Comment: @chux This is a bit of madness to details, not needed to mention in my view since this (my question) is just intended to show a bit of assembly to prove it is evaluated, and of course what I said is thus relevant to this context where caring about the sign is not needed (for these constants). Anyway, thanks for noticing it! And I did edit the answer.